# TCL incr filename

Tags: tcl, filenames

I do not want to set $outfile so many times, I would like to incr the filename.
How do I do that in TCL?

```
set incr 1
set outfile [open "file$incr.txt" w]

set infile1 "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"
set infile2 "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"
set infile3 "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"

foreach infile $infiles$incr {

    puts $oufile$incr "testing"

}
```

However , my above code , does not seem to work?

Comment: Why are you using `glob` on absolute paths without any wildcards?

Comment: Any time you've got variable variable names, consider using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [incr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/incr.htm) function :

```
set infile {}
set i 0

lappend infile "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"
lappend infile "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"
lappend infile "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"

foreach value $infile {
    incr i
    set outfile [open "file${i}.txt" w]
    foreach files $value {
        puts $outfile "testing"
    }
    close $outfile
}
```

Another solution, you can use a [array](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm) :

```
set infile(1) "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"
set infile(2) "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"
set infile(3) "[glob /a/b/c/d/a12b.txt /a/e/c/e/c123d.txt /e/e/d/e/2abd.txt ]"

foreach {key value} [array get infile] {
    set outfile [open "file${key}.txt" w]
    foreach files $value {
        puts $outfile "testing"
    }
    close $outfile

}
```

Comment: The option with the arrays looks very much like the right choice in this case. Dictionaries would also work.